# Is Viveka Satakam written by Prabodhananda Saraswati Ji Maharaj available online

Tags: krishna, gaudiya-vaishnavism

I am looking for Viveka Satakam written by Prabodhananda Saraswati,author of Vrindavan Mahimamrita